# Dealing with high traffic the right way

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am using PHP and MySQL to handle data for my multiplayer iOS game (building for Android to) and the game is tarting to be a success. I have at high traffic times about 3 calls pr. second to my "move.php" page. It takes the players move and saves the data in my db and after that returns a "completed". I need this to make sure nothing went wrong. When there is high pressure it takes about 3-5 seconds before I get "completed" back and some times more. I'm hoping to get 10 times as many users as now and are in fear of this making either the response time very long or it starts to fail... In my move.php page i have about 5 different select queries, 4 update queries and 2 insert queries. This part is optimized, but I use regular mysql and php.

I am wandering what is good practice at this point and how do I make this faster, specially for the "completed" to be sent back. I don't mind the long executing time afterwards as long the user don't experince this. Does mysqli, pro, stored procedurs etc. do anything for me?

Hoping for answers and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

When you are dealing with traffic, only one thing works [Caching, caching and more caching...](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/03/22/cache-them-if-you-can/)

You need to essentially think of an imaginary scale on one end you have users-machine and on the other extreme you have your servers-harddisk. So figure out techniques which will move your data as close to users-end as possible. the less and less you hit your servers disk the faster and responsive your website would be. This inclues techniques like -

1. client-side data storage.
2. server side caching
3. server side [web accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accelerator)
4. Proper indexing your data so that data retrieval is fast.

I can give more specific tools etc. but you can find those easily online (read `memcached` etc.), I have underlined the general thought...

Comment: Since all caching mechanisms add complexity (additional software to run, strange bugs from stale caches), I'd put "Proper indexing" to the top of the list.

Comment: there is complexity everywhere. the deeper you go the complex it gets. no running away from that. if you need speed, introduce cache at every stage is inevitable. if there is state caches, then figure out ways to deal with it. yes indexing solves some scenarios but caching is very important.

Answer (score 3):

In general, making an application faster is all about finding bottlenecks - try to profile your script to see which parts run slow, then optimize them. Measure at different points - database queries, program modules, web server requests. Don't forget to profile your application with different load profiles (number of concurrent requests/sec, overall number of users, etc)

Typical optimizations are:

- Use `EXPLAIN` for your SQL queries to see if the indexes are used correctly.
- Limit the results returned from the database (with more WHERE criteria or LIMIT statement) if possible
- Cache some results if possible.
- Scale out: Use multiple servers and a load balancer, use Replicated Mysql servers.

Using PDO or mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql module is a good idea regardless of performance concerns.

If you really want to have the "complete" return immediately, you could look into [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) - it will allow you to process the SQL in the background. However you'll need to monitor the work load - if the Queries queue up too much then the SELECT results will not reflect the current game state anymore.

Comment: In addition to these (good) suggestions, it is well worth checking what the overall time of the update script is. Could be that your script is very fast but is being let down by poor network speeds.

Answer (score 3):

Given the number of MySQL queries, I’d look at combining them. For example, for the multiple `INSERT`s, could then be ran in the same connecting, or do you issue a different statement for each of them (locking and unlocking the database)?

Also, are the queries time-sensitive? Or can a result be sent to the client and then the queries put into a job queue to be processed at a later time?

Other than that, I can only suggest what’s already been suggested: profile your code, cache where you can etc.

Comment: Some of them a time-sensitive and some are not. What should I look at if considering job queue?

Comment: If it’s not time sensitive and doesn’t have to be processed *at that very second* then I’d add it to a queue to be processed when your server can handle it. Two popular solutions are Amazon’s SQS and Beanstalkd.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent suggestions you got so far, do not forget about [PHP Accelerators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators) . They can really speed up execution times.

Also, 11 queries is not a lot, but if MySQL spends time in the Query Execution Plan for each of them, then it can really add up. So if Prepared Statements are a possibility, it's worth taken into consideration.